# Xcode Swift : Could not find member

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {

        self.logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten | PFLogInFields.DismissButton

        var logInLogoTitle = UILabel()
        logInLogoTitle.text = "Cinderella"

        self.logInViewController.PFLoginview.logo = logInLogoTitle //error: could not find member 'logo'

        self.logInViewController.delegate = self

        var signUpLogoTitle = UILabel()
        signUpLogoTitle.text = "Cinderella"

        self.signUpViewController.PFSignUpView.logo = signUpLogoTitle // error: could not find member 'logo'

        self.signUpViewController.delegate = self

        self.logInViewController.signUpController = self.signUpViewController


    }
```

i'm still a beginner and not sure what does the error meant..
anyone can help me to solve the problem please ?

Comment: Its means `PFLoginview` does name any variable named as `logo`

Comment: any idea how to solve ?

Comment: `PFLoginview` seems like a class name. are you sure you are using the right property of logInViewController. Can we see logInViewController code?

Comment: @AnilVarghese this is the code i use at first 
self.logInViewController.logInView.logo = logInLogoTitle

Comment: Which is correct. as you said in the comment below if the `logInView` is optional, use like `self.logInViewController.logInView?.logo = logInLogoTitle `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using class `PFLoginview` instead of property `logInView` you can change to logo as below

```
self.logInViewController.logInView.logo = logInLogoTitle
```

Comment: i used that code at first and this error comes out :
Value of optional type 'PFLoginView?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?' ?

Comment: Insert `?` after `logInView ` like `logInView?.logo`. In swift optional variable need to unwrapped. Its look like `logInView` is optional variable

Comment: i got an error saying Expected Declaration on the very last row of my code..
can i know how to solve it ?